# Windows Service Not Working Getting Stopped Without Error

Tags: c#, windows, service

i have searched everywhere for this but im still stuck at this for past couple of days. I have got a service that is used to call a method after every 5 minutes

```
public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private Timer _timer;
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            _timer = new Timer(5*60*1000);
            _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimerElapsed);
            _timer.AutoReset = true;
            _timer.Start();
        }
        private void OnTimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            var FuncFlag = false;
            _timer.Stop();
            send_email("Going To Call API MEthod");
            FuncFlag = Authorization();

            _timer.Start();

            if (!FuncFlag)
            {
                send_email("Service Failure for Authorization");
            }
        }
        public static bool Authorization()
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://**.**.**.**:****/");
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/values/checkauthorization/).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                send_email("Response Success");
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                send_email("Response Failed");
                return false;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            _timer.Stop();
            _timer.Dispose();
        }
}
```

On the method i need to get some values to have them stored in the DB. I just want to call this method at every 5 minutes please help me if i have missed anything in this or let me know if there is a better way to achieve this.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong.  But, you're also not checking for any exceptions in Authorization.  There are many reasons why HttpClient can throw an exception.  If it does, you should see an event in the Windows Event log about an application crash. Or, try removing the call to authorization to see if it works as expected otherwise.  If it does, you know the problem is somewhere in Authorization.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @PeterRitchie, this is what bugs me the authorization method executes fine everytime the service calls it as i have logging enabled in that method and it returns success but after calling the method the service stops for no reason. Also it runs fine for a long period of time and then shuts itself down.  ill check the logs further.

Comment: Also one thing i noticed it whenever i log off from the server , after some time the service stops i.e whenever the server is in idle state the service stops, the state of the service remains "running" but it doesnt call the method on every interval. Is there any setting i need to implement on the server related to that ?